# Applying the concept of interfaces and abstract classes in a program

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I was working on this question and I was wondering I have got it right.

Consider the interface MusicInterface which has a constant data member, TYPE,
which is equal to ‘Nice Music’ and a method play() which displays the TYPE on
console. The class StringedInstrument implements the interface
MusicInstrument.

i) Write the Java code for the interface MusicInstrument.

ii) Implement the abstract class StringedInstrument having variables
numberOfStrings of type integer and name of type String. No
implementation of method play is possible at this point.

iii) Implement the concrete class ElectricGuitar which is a subclass of
StringedInstrument having a constructor that initializes the name and
numberOfStrings and appropriate methods.

**MusicInstrument class**

```
public interface MusicInterface {

  final String TYPE= "Nice Music";

  public void play();

}
```

**StringedInstrument class**

```
public abstract class StringedInstrument implements MusicInterface {
    public int numberOfStrings;
    public String name;
}
```

**ElectricGuitar class**

```
public class ElectricGuitar extends StringedInstrument{

  public ElectricGuitar(int numberOfString, String name){
    super();
  }

@Override
public void play() {

    System.out.println("The type of music is: "+TYPE);
    }

 }
```

The question seems to be pretty straightforward so I was wondering if I made any mistake in understanding it.

Comment: This question seems off topic for this site.

Comment: In other words, "did I get it right" is not very specific and not helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes for writing conventional Java code:

Change the visibility of the declared fields in your Abstract class `StringedInstrument` to be at least `protected` (or package-private). These fields are part of the state of the class and should be properly encapsulated.

Also, your `ElectricGuitar` constructor is kinda useless. It receives 2 parameters that are never used and the `StringedInstrument`'s respective fields remain uninitialized. You should create a matching constructor in `StringedInstrument` and initialize the `numberOfStrings` and `name` fields in it, something like:

```
public StringedInstrument(int numberOfString, String name){
    this.numberOfStrings = numberOfStrings;
    this.name = name;
}
```

and `ElectricGuitar` would use this super constructor:

```
public ElectricGuitar(int numberOfStrings, String name){
    super(numberOfStrings, name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason for the class StringedInstrument to be abstract if it does not include any polymorphic abstract methods. I don't think this context would satisfy an appropriate example of abstract inherency.

That being said, whether you make it abstract or not, you should include in StringedInstrument:

```
public StringedInstrument(int numberOfStrings, String name) {
     this.numberOfStrings = numberOfStrings;
     this.name = name;
}
```

and in Electric guitar:

```
public ElectricGuitar(int numberOfStrings, String name) {
    super(numberOfStrings, name);
}
```

I suppose if you put the TYPE in StringedInstrument you could do:

```
public abstract String getType();
```

and then in your specific class (ElectricGuitar) customize what getType() produces which is also a pretty weak use of an interface.

Answer (score -1):

```
public abstract class StringedInstrument implements MusicInterface {
public int numberOfStrings;
public String name;

public StringedInstrument()
{
    // This gets called by ElectricGuitar() constructor
}

 @Override
 public void play() 
{
    // I meant, you can also HAVE AN IMPLEMENTATION HERE. My Corrections
    // OMITTING THIS METHOD BODY DECLARATION, WON'T CAUSE COMPILE ERRORS
    //  THAT WAS A BAD JOKE BY ME
    System.out.println("The type of music is: "+TYPE + " In " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() );
}


}
```

Your Code stands solid

Comment: But in the second part of the ques, it mentioned that in the StringedInstrument class, no implementation of play() is possible.

Comment: I am seriously sorry on that one, you were absolutely right, I actually confused that abstract class force overloads of interface when implemented, this happens only in concrete implementation. My Bad. You are good to go for the code, it is absolutely fine

Comment: It's totally fine ;) Thanks for your help